# Injecting EJB into CDI managed bean

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

I'm having problems injecting EJB into CDI Managed Bean.

Lets start from my `@Remote` interface

```
@Remote
public interface TestInterface {
    public String getHello();
}
```

[image]

And its implementation

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean implements TestInterface {
    @Override
    public String getHello() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

[image]

And my `ManagedBean` implementation,

```
@Named(value = "managed_library")
@SessionScoped
public class LibraryManagedBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private TestInterface testBean;

    public String getHello() {
        return testBean.getHello();
    }
}
```

[image]

This simple example isnt working for me tho :/

> Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref
>   name=web.LibraryManagedBean/testBean,Remote 3.x interface
>   =test.TestInterface,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=test.TestInterface,refType=Session into class web.LibraryManagedBean: Lookup failed for
>   'java:comp/env/web.LibraryManagedBean/testBean' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}

Looks like it can't find bean to inject... but why? what am I missing?

Comment: Your `@Named` bean is a CDI managed one, not a jsf managed one

Comment: En please make your title More explicit in What is actually Happening

Comment: And I'd say your error is pretty clear... It tries to inject a remote ejb-ref with a certain name via a lookup in the java context and cannot find that. Try to see if it is also deployed with that name. Otherwise 'just' fix that .

Comment: In theory you could also have problem with the remote interface and its impl being in different archives, depending on what server are you on (due to how archive separation works there). Also, I'd use `@Inject` instead of `@EJB` although it shouldn't be the cause of this error.

Comment: Injecting references to remote EJBs is something a GlassFish expert *might* be able to do, if it is possible at all. It would need to be possible to configure an external JNDI context in your server, which I know is possible on WildFly and WebSphere, but I don't see it done very often. Are you sure that you need to use `@Remote`?